# srand() scope in C++

Tags: c++, random, srand

When you call `srand()` inside of a function, does it only seed `rand()` inside of that function?

Here is the function `main` where `srand()` is called.

```
int main(){
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    random_number();
}

void random_number(){
    rand();
}
```

The function `random_number` where `rand()` is used is outside of where `srand()` was called.

So my question is - If you seed `rand()` by using `srand()`, can you use the seeded `rand()` outside of where `srand()` was called? Including functions, different files, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`srand` is in effect globally, we can see this by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), we can reference to C standard because C++ falls back to the C standard for C library functions and it says (*emphasis mine*):

> The srand function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random
>   numbers to be returned **by subsequent calls to rand**. If srand is then called with the
>   same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand is
>   called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated
>   as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1.

It does not restrict its effect to the scope it was used in, it just says it effects *subsequent calls to rand*

The example of a portable implementation provided in the draft standard makes it more explicit that the effect is global:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
   next = seed;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

No, it applies globally. It is not limited to the function, not even to the thread.

cplusplus.com has more information:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/